# append a close tag with jquery

Tags: jquery

i have this situation:

here start foor loop ...

```
$("#sez:last").append("<div id=\"sezDati\" class=\"counter_"+d+"\">"+name+"</div>");         if ( d  ==  6  ){ $("#sez:last").find(".counter_6").after().wrap("</div><div id=\"sezDati\">");
}
d++
```

After 6 div #sezDati i need to append first a close tag  then reopen a sezDati div...
Any help??

thanks

Comment: You selector seems to be wrong. What you are trying to do is that selecting the last element from elements that have ids sez. Having more than 1 element with the same id is invalid.

Comment: Ok but it not work also if i use class instead id...

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't be using the same id for more than one element. Use your counter to generate the dynamic ids and use those instead. Also why are you using `.after().wrap()` in this case? Surely what you need is just an `.after()`.

Something like:

```
$("#sez:last").append("<div id=\"sezDati_"+d+"\" class=\"sezDati\">"+name+"</div>");
if ( d  ==  6  ){ 
   $("#sez:last").find(".sezDati_6").after("</div><div id=\"sezDati\">");
}
d++
```